# A multiple choice question about $e^{-|x|}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

For $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = \exp (-|x|)$

Is the function

a) bounded

b) differentiable

c) $f(\mathbb{R})$ is compact

d) $f$ has a minimum

According to the question only one answer is correct. I think it's either a) or b), but I'm really confused as to which one is correct.

Comment: Can your function have negative values? How about zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is a). It cannot be d) because in order to have a minimum the value must actually be attained. The infimum of your function is $0$ but it is not attained for any real numbers. It cannot be c) because the range of your function does not contain $0$ although $0$ is a limit point of the range, thus its range is not a closed set (and therefore not compact). It cannot be b) because there is a cusp at $x=0$.

Comment: Ah I get it now. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. You can click the green checkmark next to my answer to accept it and mark the question as answered for future users.